# If $A<S_\mathbb{N},$ are there always $B,C<S_\mathbb{N}$ with $B\cap C=A?$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let A be a proper (non maximal) subgroup of the countable symmetric group $S_\mathbb{N}.$ In general, can we always find $B,C$ proper subgroups of $S_\mathbb{N}$ with $A<B$ and $A<C$ such that $B\cap C=A?$

I found such an A with this property and I want to know if this makes it special or if every such A has this property.

Comment: Presumably, you want to exclude $B=A$ or $C=A$....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I just went and clarified.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Every bijection

Comment: And just to further clarify, by $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ do you mean all bijections $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, or all bijections of finite support only? All bijections; gotcha. You should say that, as it is not always a given.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Really? I've never seen $S_\Omega$ denote anything but the bijections from $\Omega$ to $\Omega.$

Comment: Some folks want permutations to have finite support, and use $S_X$ to mean the group of all "permutations" of $X$.

Comment: To provide further context, every permutation group involved in my research contains $S_F,$ taken to be the permutations of finite support. In fact, I take this as a matter of definition. Finitely supported permutations have every possible property one could want in my context, so it is not very useful for me to consider them.

Comment: Since $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ has maximal subgroups, such a subgroup would be a counterexample. Some citations: "Maximal subgroups of infinite symmetric groups" by Brazil, Covington, Penttila, Praeger, and Woods, Proc. London Math. Soc (3) 68 (1994) 77-111; and "Some maximal subgroups of infinite symmetric groups" by Covington, MacPherson, and Dugald, Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 47 (1996) no 187, 297-311.  (Question has now been modified to exclude maximal subgroups)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I just realized that I want to exclude these cases as well, as I have yet to encounter a maximal subgroup in my research.

Comment: You should add $C>A$ otherwise it is quite direct. I think what you mean is that in the lattice of the subgroups, $A$ is a node that has at least 2 "successors". If $A$ is a subgroup of two different maximal subgroups it works fine

Comment: I haven't thought about this in detail, but what about the intransitive subgroup with two orbits, the even and the odd numbers. This is not maximal because it has index two in the corresponding imprimitive group that is preserves this partition, but I don't immediately see how to express it as a proper intersection of two proper subgroups. On second thoughts, perhaps I want to take the group generated by this subgroup and the (normal) subgroup of all finitary permutations.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace While the new phrasing is clearer, "$A\lt B,C$" clearly meant to convey that $A$ was proper in both $B$ and $C$. Otherwise, the "$,C$" is just hanging there doing nothing.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Not sure how "is a subgroup of two different maximal subgroups" implies it. In $Q_8$, the trivial subgroup is a subgroup of two different maximal subgroups, but is not the intersection of two proper subgroups that properly contain it.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace yes, that is exactly what I want. It forms a diamond shaped lattice with two distinct intermediate subgroups. But as Arturo said, it is not as simple as two maximal subgroups.

Comment: yes I figured it out while eating...